# Can't seem to access my array values, even when it working

Tags: java, arrays

For some reason, I can't seem to access my array values outside of the for loop I created. I have declared the array locally. But when I have to user input a value, for some reason the in bound values keep giving me `0`. Is there a way to get the information from an array inside a for loop, to be "generalize", that way it can be used in other functions.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Array {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {

        int[] array = new int[100];
        try{
        for(int i: array){
            array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            }
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter an index for which you would like to see: ");
            int index = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(array[index]);

        }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
            System.out.println("Please enter in an index thta is not out of bounds");
        }finally{System.out.println("--------------------------");}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this for loop and it should work:

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
```

The problem in your code was:

when you do `for(int i: array)`, you are just instructing that just copy the contents of array from array[0] to array[99] to i, which will be zero all the time as no other value is being set.
Enhanced for loops should be used for less code iteration only

TO understand how enhanced for loop works, try the loop given below for your understanding:

```
int[] array = new int[100];
        array[0]=1;array[1]=2;

        for(int i: array){
           // array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

when you run this code, the first and second element will print 1 and 2.

Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using enhanced `for-loop` You are not initializing each element of the array, the only element that gets the value is the first element zero. When you declare an array all the value are set to zero. So, in your enhanced `for-loop` you are setting the value of `array[0]` and that's the reason you are getting zero as an output.

Replace the enhanced `for-loop` with this:

```
       int[] array = new int[100];
        try{
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100);

            System.out.println(array[i]);
            }
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter an index for which you would like to see: ");
            int index = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(array[index]);

        }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
            System.out.println("Please enter in an index thta is not out of bounds");
        }finally{
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }
```

Comment: Well thats a face palm to the head. But logic wise shouldnt an "enhanced"  for have the relative capabilities of a regular for loop, and then some ?

Comment: @Dcdw51 I have added explanation to my answer, check it out. Enhanced for loop is just for iteration and not for usual array assigning as the index value wont get incremented for the assigning variable array

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the array, you give it 100 indexes. They automatically become all 0's. Your for each loops is just assigning a random number to the 0th index in your array, and everything else remains 0. You're not actually accessing the ith element in the array!

This should fix your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] array = new int[100];
        try{
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            }

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter an index for which you would like to see: ");
            int index = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(array[index]);

        }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
            System.out.println("Please enter in an index thta is not out of bounds");
        }finally{System.out.println("--------------------------");}

        }
}
```